# How to pass multiple variables to onload in Angular ng-include?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, recursion

In my Angular program, I would like to use a template that can be passed two variables.

```
<div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'" onload="{obj: someObject, value: value}"></div>
```

I wish the above line would work but it doesn't. I can't figure out how to pass these two variables. My template resembles the toy template below (I'm aiming for the same recursive effect).

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate.html">
         <h2> {{obj.title}} </h2>
         <h2> {{value}}-{{$parent.value}}  </h2>
         <div ng-include="'endpointTemplate.html'" onload="{obj: someObject.innerObjects, value: {{$parent.value + value}}"></div>
    </script>
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

i think this may work:

```
<div ng-include="'myTemplate.html'" ng-init="obj=someObject; value= $parent.value"></div>
```

Comment: Eureka it does! How did you figure that out?

Comment: it is the common things.whenever you have to assign value to more than one variable,just assign and seprate with semicolon.for your convenience i searched  documentation for that but i did not get.sorry for that.

Comment: Not sure if you meant to use `ng-init` but this only works with `onload` for me.